# Why does this identity hold?

Tags: integration

\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k \overset != \int_0^{\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}xdx,~\text{where}~\displaystyle a_k = \left|\int_{\pi k}^{\pi(k+1)}\frac{\sin x}xdx\right|
\end{equation*}

I don't understand the $(-1)^k$.

Comment: It's the sign of $\sin x$ on the interval $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$.

Comment: Of course! That makes sense. Thank you. :)